# Adjust Control's Size/Position With Screen Resolution

Tags: c#, winforms

I have noticed that some applications change their controls position to adjust them as much as possible in the resolution as possible, If window is maximized they set themselves in such a way that over all GUI looks balanced. My question is that is it possible to make or implement this functionality in Visual studio 2010 C#?

Comment: You are looking for a layout management system like WPF.

Comment: In Winforms........How can i do it

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can place your controls in a [`TableLayoutPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx) then

- set its docking property to `Left, Top, Right, Bottom`
- set all controls docking properties to `Left, Top, Right, Bottom` or less if more appropriate
- set the columns and rows size of your `TableLayoutPanel` as "percent" or "fixed" at your convenience.

Take a look at that [walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/991eahec%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). It's not easy to implement at the first time, but go through the whole tutorial and you'll get a good idea on how to do it.