# different form size on different machine

Tags: c#, winforms, screen-resolution

I've created C# project, which includes several Forms.

I tried my project on different machines and forms are displayed too large on some machines while small on others.

So they do not fit to screen size automatically.

What should i do to display each form in proper way on different machines with different screen size,different display card and different resolution.......?

I googled and found that control.dock property can solve this problem but dock property does not allow to manage/move controls where i wish on form.

And i think almost all programmers have faced this problem.

So please provide the best option available.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into anchoring controls...  I would build a form based on the smaller size form, then set the anchor properties so when the form is resized to a larger, the controls remain in same relative position as smaller, yet your code does its own thing as normal.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to build your form with the smaller size possible as said by *DRapp* and enable form to be resized and maximized. In order for the controls to be nicely and rightly placed, use a [`TableLayoutPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx) to place your controls and play with the docking properties.

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8104396/825024).